# Added meshes will not be aligned with the current transform orientation

Tags: transforms, coordinates

I have put an object in its own layer to edit it separately.

Changing the transform orientation to local shows the axes of the object itself instead of the global ones.

[image: local axes]

However, if I add a new mesh, it will get a rotation of that mesh (a plane in this example) that is aligned with the global axes.

Why?

[image: An added plane]

## edit

Here is how I expected the plane to be aligned: to the local axes.

[image: expected plane alignment]

Comment: That is what *Local* transform orientation means, it aligns with the currently selected object's local X Y and Z axis, which takes its rotations into account

Comment: In the picture, we see the opposite.

Comment: Please, correct me if I am wrong, but that plane is aligned with global axes, isn´t it? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: In the pictures I see what is expected, newly added plane is aligned with global coordinates and so are its local axis, the other object seems rotated and so do its axis too. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: I edited the question with a screenshot of the expected mesh alignment.

Answer (score 3):

After selecting your 'local coordinate' object, go to Edit Mode and select a face the represents your 'floor' rotation. Shift Numpad 7 will let you align your view to the Top view of this face, and in Object mode add your new object - and in the F6 panel/ tool bar operator panel, check 'align to view' and the new object should be aligned to your 'local coordinate' object.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The downsides with this method is that I will have to 1. select the object, 2. change the view (to topview) and after I have added the object 3. popup a dialog and 4. check a box, which adds 4 steps for every time. The view will also be changed by the operation which would disturb the work flow. Thanks again, I appreciate it, maybe I will not choose this method if there are others to select from.

Comment: You can set your new transform orientation in the N Panel and then use that instead of 'local' space. There are addons that exist somewhere for alignment, allowing you to use some really interesting snap transforms. Also, you can change your user prefs to align new objects to view.